# Rails "includes" Method and Avoiding N+1 Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't understand the Rails `includes` method as well as I'd like, and I ran into an issue that I'm hoping to clarify. I have a **Board** model that `has_many :members` and `has_many :lists` (and a list `has_many :cards`). In the following **boards controller**, the `show` method looks as follows:

```
def show
  @board = Board.includes(:members, lists: :cards).find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

Why is the `includes` method needed here? Why couldn't we just use `@board = Board.find(params[:id])` and then access the members and lists via `@board.members` and `@board.lists`? I guess I'm not really seeing why we would need to prefetch. It'd be awesome if someone could detail why this is more effective in terms of SQL queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the Rails docs:

> Eager loading is the mechanism for loading the associated records of
>   the objects returned by Model.find using as few queries as possible.

When you simply load a record and later query its different relationships, you have to run a query each time. Take this example, also from the Rails docs:

```
clients = Client.limit(10)

clients.each do |client|
  puts client.address.postcode
end
```

This code executes a database call 11 times to do something pretty trivial, because it has to do each lookup, one at a time.

Compare the above code to this example:

```
clients = Client.includes(:address).limit(10)

clients.each do |client|
  puts client.address.postcode
end
```

This code executes a database call 2 times, because all of the necessary associations are included at the onset.

[Here's a link to the pertinent section of the Rails docs.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

**Extra**

A point to note as of recent: if you do a more complex query with an associated model like so:

`Board.includes(:members, lists: :cards).where('members.color = ?', 'foo').references(:members)`

You need to make sure to include the appended `references(:used_eager_loaded_class)` to complete the query.

Comment: I believe you mean "This code executes eleven SQL queries" the code inside the loop will execute the same number of times whether you use includes or not. The difference is the number of round trips to the DB.

Comment: I can see that in your example we have numerous (let's say "n") Client models, so if we didn't use eager loading, then for each model we'd have to query "n" times. But in my example aren't we just finding one Board member with `params[:id]`?

Comment: Yes. In your example, if all you needed was to locate a user, then you wouldn't need the `#includes` at all.

Comment: But if you were listing `@board.members` it would cause 1 query per member. This is usually not noticeable in development but once your app starts to grow and you get a large number of entries in your database it will make responses get slower and slower until your server starts to lock up.

Comment: @CollinGraves, then I'm confused by why the `#includes` method is used in the above code at all? We aren't iterating through a bunch of boards and querying each of them. I should say that the above code is not written by me, but by someone with a lot of experience, so I assume it's the most efficient way.

Comment: @max is correct here. If all you're doing here is querying the pertinent `User`, then it's ok to drop the `#includes`. If you plan to do anything with an associated model via your instance variable, however, it makes sense to eager load the appropriate relationships.

Comment: @fibono see the comment above ^^^

Comment: I think I'm getting what you guys mean. If I didn't use eager loading and for instance called @board.members at different points in the `#show` method, then each call would be a SQL query.

Comment: Often programmers err on the side of caution - a join query is only very marginally slower than a simple select - a N+1 query problem which fires 50 SQL queries can be extremely slow. So you add a `.includes` before you actually need it.

Comment: @fibono if you found my answer helpful, feel free to mark this question as closed by accepting it :) thanks for the revision suggestions, max